# Authorization header, still getting 401 Unauthorized

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to make use of Microsoft Graph API and have been getting `401`´s all day without any progress. Please tell me if you see any error!

```cs
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", access_token);

HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String response = restTemplate
    .exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class)
    .getBody();
System.out.println(response);
```

Edit: I only want to know if there is anything wrong with how I am sending the authorization. The `access_token` is set properly through different call to Azure and the application has the permissions needed to call the API.

2nd Edit: url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages". A large number of other endpoints have been tested too.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized

at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
```

3rd Edit:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you are missing "Bearer" word before the access_token?

Comment: "Bearer " is currently part of the string access_token

Comment: Sadly. Would be glad for such a minor mistake here :)

Comment: What scopes have you requested and which endpoint are you calling? An example of the JSON payload you're getting back would be helpful as well.

Comment: Edited accordingly.

Comment: Can you tell us whether you are requesting an access token using the client_credentials flow (application only call)?  Can you provide a snippet of your token that show the permissions that were actually granted to your app (i.e. the "scp" claim and the "roles" claim) please?

Comment: I got the access token by calling https://login.microsoftonline.com/ <tenant>/oauth2/token and extracting the token from that response body.

Comment: Added image showing permissions given

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to also have the code that you are using to request tokens, but from what you shared - including the from screen shot and your description - you are requesting access to the *List messages* (/me/messages) endpoint.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages), to access this scope, you are required to have **Mail.Read**, or **Mail.ReadWrite** scopes. Your screen shot shows that your app registration information has *Read calendars in all mailboxes* and *Read all groups* as **Application level permission** and *Sign-in and read user profile* as **Delegated permission** - none of these scopes define permissions to access user's email.

Because you are trying to use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages - my assumption is that you are using delegated permissions (an application would not know what 'me' is) - therefore, you must add **Mail.Read** as delegated permission and make sure that you use this scope when requesting your token.

So, if this is not helpful, please also add the code that you are using to request the token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to call many endpoints. With the permissions posted in the screenshot, what endpoints do you think I have permission to call?

Comment: @Skroovel - with current set of permissions, it depends on which context your application is running:<br/> - If your app runs as [app context/ service to service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) or obtain tokens in behalf of users.<br/> If your app runs as app context, then you should be able to read any group in the organization and any user calendar. If your application as delegated, then your app can only see the basic user's profile (name, email, others)

Comment: Being running the app on behalf - which is the most common, your app currently can only make use of do a GET to the ['me' endpoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get)